# Ckfinder (.Net) No XML Output from Connector.aspx

Tags: .net, xml, ckeditor, ckfinder

So I have integrated CKfinder with CKeditor. Everything is working fine on the localhost. After uploading it to the server, the Browser Server functionality gives the following error:

**It was not possible to properly load the XML response from the web server. Raw response from the server:** Empty response

After investigating using Firebug, I have found out that there is no xml response from the server. Instead it's sending the following html content:

```
<html><head><title></title><!-- <script language="javascript">window.location.replace("http://www.domainname.com/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?command=Init&type=Images");</script> --></head><body></body></html>
```

To add to the surprise, accessing the same connector url directly through the browser is producing the right xml:

```
<Connector resourceType="Images">
<Error number="0"/>
<ConnectorInfo enabled="true" imgWidth="1600" imgHeight="1200" s="" c="" thumbsEnabled="true" uploadCheckImages="false" thumbsUrl="/Assets/_ckthumbs/" thumbsWidth="100" thumbsHeight="100" thumbsDirectAccess="false"/>
<Resource Types><ResourceType name="Images" url="/Assets/" maxSize="0" allowedExtensions="bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png" deniedExtensions="" hash="be4f06df98eb7cc3" hasChildren="true" acl="255"/></ResourceTypes>
<PluginsInfo/>
</Connector>
```

Here are the screenshots to be clear:

[image: response in firebug after xhr request]

[image: browser output after direct url request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to help somebody but the problem was not with ckfinder or ckeditor configuration. The ckeditor was installed on ssl enabled pages and the cms was setup to force the redirection to non-ssl url for non secure sections. Assigning ckeditor and ckfinder folders as secure areas stopped the redirection to the non-ssl url. The incorrect output above was due to the redirection code in the cms and not ckfinder.